# Splitting a string by integers in Python

Tags: python, regex, text

Lets say i have a string `'hvusdhf4673bfiw67bfe'`.
 I want to split it in `'hvusdhf'` and `'bfiw'` and `'bfe'` using `str.split()`.I have not been able to do that. Can somebody help here?

Comment: Code attempts so far? SO is **not** a code writing service

Comment: I attempted str.split('\d').It did not work. After that i tried to find something on internet,But could not find anything. Then i posted it here. I do not understand why would somebody thumbs down this question, I am not posting questions here for fun. I posted only when i could not find anything related to that. Is SO not for beginners?

Comment: Please edit the post to add more info

Comment: Most important information: what is the criteria by which you want to split - it's not clear from your question? Is it fixed length of split strings or some substring?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex

```
import re
re.split('\d+', 'hvusdhf4673bfiw67bfe')
```